# Unselect all should hide all the data

Tags: powerbi

Just like how it is done in Tableau. when you click on 'Select all' all the data is shown in the dashboard as visuals, but when you click 'Select all' again and the tick boxes disappear, all the data should also disappear, is there a way to achieve that in Power BI?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't currently possible but if you post your use case on LinkedIn with the #PBICoreVisuals tag, Miguel Myers may incorporate the requirement into the next big update for slicers.